# How can I capture PowerShell lines as they are executed ina powershell script from a c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, winforms

I am currently developing a .Net Framework C# WinForms application that executes PowerShell scripts using `System.Management.Automation`.

When a PowerShell script executes, I want a way to capture each line of code from the script as it is being executed, as opposed to just reading the whole file as a string initially.

I am building a machine this way, and want it to function similar to the [HMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface) of a [CNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_control) machine.

It seems that `Powershell.HistoryString()` gives the history but i think it only gives back all of it at once.

Let me know if i can provide more info. Thanks!

Comment: What does HMI and CNC stand for?

Comment: CNC is computer numerical control, a method of controlling industrial machinery such as mills, lathes, routers, and saws. An HMI is a human-machine interface, basically a GUI

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **minimal C# example** using the **[PowerShell SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart)** and **[`System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser)**, the PowerShell language parser:

**Limitations**:

- This simplistic implementation loops over the input scripts own top-level statements only, and treats *compound* language statements such as `foreach` and `while` as *single* statements.
- Nested processing is possible *with limitations*,<sup>[1]</sup> and requires substantially more effort. Ultimately, this is *no* substitution for an IDE with a debugger that allows you to step through code.

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Language;

static class Program {
  public static void Main() {

    // ADD YOUR SCRIPT FILE PATH HERE.
    var scriptFilePath = @"/path/to/your/script.ps1";

    // Parse the script file (error handling omitted).
    var ast = Parser.ParseFile(scriptFilePath, out _, out _);

    // Iterate over the script file's statements one by one, printing their
    // source code, followed by executing and printing their results.
    using (var ps = PowerShell.Create()) 
    {

      foreach (var stmt in ast.EndBlock.Statements)
      {
        // Print the statement's source code.
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("» Executing:\n{0}\n\n»  Result:\n", stmt.ToString()));
        // Execute the statement and print its for-display formatted results, using
        // an aux. Out-String call.
        foreach (var o in ps.AddScript(string.Format(". {{ {0} }} | Out-String", stmt.ToString())).Invoke())
        {
          Console.WriteLine(o);
        }
        ps.Commands.Clear();
      }

    }

  }
}
```

The language parser is needed, because PowerShell statements can span multiple lines, so you need to what block of lines constitutes a single statement.

Sample output:

```
» Executing:
Get-ChildItem -File |
  Measure-Object Length -Sum -Maximum

»  Result:


Count             : 2
Average           :
Sum               : 1479
Maximum           : 1122
Minimum           :
StandardDeviation :
Property          : Length



» Executing:
Get-Date -Format yyyy

»  Result:

2023
```

---

<sup>[1] For instance, the AST representation of a [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) statement is of type [`System.Management.Automation.Language.LoopStatementAst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.LoopStatementAst), which has a `.Condition` and a `.Body` property, and you'd have to invoke these individually, and decide when the body is done executing. *Nested* loops with *labeled* `break` and `continue` statements that cross statement boundaries would be all but impossible to handle this way.</sup>

Comment: I've not actually tried this, but I'm guessing a caveat is that it only "steps" through the top-level statements - if you have nesting (e.g. ```for``` loops, ```if``` statements) or function calls it will output the entire nested scope or just the function *call* rather than step through the nesting like an IDE would (i.e. it does "step over" rather than "step into")?

Comment: @mclayton Correct - I mean, what would the alternative even be? You can't execute `foreach($thing in $collection){`, the parser will tell you the input is incomplete :)

Comment: Good point, @mclayton - please see my update, which states the limitations of this approach clearly. You _could_ dig into a `foreach` loop, for instance, (its AST representation has `.Condition` and `.Body` properties), but that gets messy fast. Without knowing the specifics of the use case, I'll leave the answer as is.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I guess you could dig into the `LoopStatementAst` AST and execute the `.Condition` and `.Body` individually, but please see my previous comment.

Comment: But then you're emulating the command processor, not powershell.exe... I guess whether that's desirable depends on OPs motivation here :)